# Conditional code synchronization only for specific threads

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking, nonblocking

Assume that there are three groups of thread. lets say A,B, and C.

I want to create a code block in a method that blocking occurs between A and B type threads , C threads are allowed in all cases of the method invocation including the blocking portion.

In other words, if a A type of thread is in a blocked code portion, B is blocked but C is not blocked.

Do you have an idea if it is possible to do it? If so how this could be done?

Comment: What is your reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Locks aren't only for mutual exclusion; they also provide a memory barrier that ensures visibility across threads. If C group threads are sharing any data with A and B threads, you'll still need a memory barrier. I wouldn't be surprised if what your really need is a `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: My question does not related to real case problem but a possible scenario which I can run into in the future.

Comment: You won't run into this problem. A lock either needs to happen for all threads or not at all, as the purpose of a lock is to defend against multiple access. What makes sense is something like a read/write lock, so a locking based on usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have helper locking methods :

```
private final ReentrantLock mLock = new ReentrantLock();

void conditionalLock() {
    ThreadGroup group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    if (group.equals(groupA) || group.equals(groupB)) {
        mLock.lock();
    }
}
```

**Edit** changed/simplified condition as nicely suggested by *erickson*

```
void conditionalUnlock() {
    if (mLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
        mLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Then, in the method of the same class :

```
    conditionalLock();
    try {
        // block you want to synchronize between threads of group A & B
    } finally {
        conditionalUnlock();
    }
```

Comment: what differentiates A,B from C?

Comment: What to pass inside `if` block?

Comment: In `conditionalUnlock()`, I'd suggest testing whether the lock `isHeldByCurrentThread()`, rather than looking at the group again.

Comment: @erickson totally makes sense, thanks, I will update the code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats a ugly way to do it, but i have an idea.

You could name Your `Threads` and do an if statment checking the name (type of Thread).

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().contains("A") || Thread.currentThread().getName().contains("B")){
    synchronized(this){
        //do stuff
    }
}else{
    //do stuff or even check if its type C
}
```

Comment: your solution is correct if Threads are grouped by their name. However kiruwka's solution is more general.

Comment: Yes it is more general, I agree. :)

Comment: Well, I honestly don't see significant difference between my approach and your answer, except that you will have to duplicate block of code `//do stuff`. so +1 to you too.

Comment: @mmc18 thanks. btw, no offense, but I think you can re-formulate title of your question to be more specific, like "conditional code synchronization only for specific threads". "Blocking/unblocking" seems to refer to a bit different concept

Comment: you are right, even I hardly found relation between title and question, I have changed it and now current one is more meaningful title.